# Дешифратор php файлов

Tags: php, вирусы

Всем привет. Вирус вымогатель зашифровал много файлов. В частности интересует реально ли расшифровать php файл? В кодировке Hexadecimal файл имеет следующий вид: (в UTF-8 текст другой, но копируется только одна строка.)

```
081b 24cf e9af 3fab 27e9 36c9 276f c544
2830 1e8e f546 7a1d 8078 ad30 98ff b716
0e6c a023 163d ecf6 37ee 38a0 7ef9 ce48
3beb 8585 2690 8d1f c322 5178 464a 02ea
2817 e4e0 81e1 9194 0339 7419 30c4 df8d
8e6c 6ef0 49d9 fa76 bc06 8733 d73b 2400
2a06 4b95 76b2 c43c 813f 31c3 b4ba 383f
eca4 4505 4f7a dfff 9bce 3847 070b 8fb5
ab16 e8a3 0198 a2e2 a7f7 991a 95ea 4ff5
9f21 3b32 de02 0ed5 bb77 4b9b 5626 dba6
3c1a e0ce 4d10 8685 9353 0c4e 3e2c 789a
b0ca 8588 8031 0572 6b4d fdbb fec2 7810
1b9d bf9c 0f4e 5b45 f563 d80b 97a0 8df4
cb7a fa2a 54e2 a17c 3dd8 87aa 5b6f 3c2c
c6b9 955b a679 d066 8349 4710 6ce8 e3bd
```

Comment: Если бы было можно расшифровать без участия вымогателя, само его существование не имело бы смысла :)

Comment: @andreymal , ну многие файлы можно расшифровать, а платить вымогателю нет смысла, он все равно не раскодирует файлы

Comment: @Homie бэкапы то есть?

Comment: @DaemonHK конкретно этих файлов некоторых нет

Comment: @Homie смотря какой вымогатель, может и раскодирует. Если не раскодирует, то зачем ему вообще шифровать, можно же просто удалить или записать мусор вместо шифрования

Comment: поделитесь плиз опытом, как удалось расшифровать многие файлы.

Comment: Вы приложили в вопрос просто набор случайных байт. Можно ли их расшифровать? Да, их можно расшифровать во что угодно (и каким угодно алгоритмом). Но что бы расшифровать их в исходный текст, нужно знать, каким образом они были зашифрованы - то есть проводить анализ кода шифровальщика.

Comment: @defrag об этом можно посмотреть на ютубе, файлы можно расшифровать, если у них расширения после шифровки da vinci, enigma, vault, xtbl, cbf

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не зная алгоритм шифрования и ключ, которым данные были зашифрованы, расшифровка не представляется возможной.
В зависимости от затрат, проще либо заплатить за расшифровку, либо восстановить файлы из бэкапов/вручную.

Comment: понял, спасибо.